# How can I decline the latest update?

Tags: updates, htc-droid-incredible

The latest update for the HTC Incredible looks to be mostly bloatware and a few small fixes. I'd rather not update, but the constant reminders are super annoying. Is there anything I can do, or is my only recourse to go ahead and install the update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when I originally rooted on my Droid with Stock ROM.  Eventually a newer version of Froyo came out and I had to upgrade (and lose root) or switch to a custom ROM.  I ended up switching to CyanogenMod.  No more nagging update messages and I kept root.  You might want to consider rooting your phone and switching to a custom rom for the Incredible.